# neo4j and groovy: automatic loading of paths of variable length

Tags: groovy, neo4j

I have large amount of data that consists of users who visit web sites. I have time stamp for each visit. Using the http://jexp.de/blog/2012/10/parallel-batch-inserter-with-neo4j/ script, I created a graph that has a separate path for each page

```
U1-->T1-->P1
|
 --->T2-->P2
etc.
```

Now, I would want to have the following structure:

U1->T1->P1->T2->P2...

Obviously, each user visits different number of pages. I have the file that looks like this:

```
person,time,place
U1,t1,P1
U1,t2,P2 
U1,t3,P3
U2,t4,P1
U2,t5,P6
```

each user sequence is ordered by visit time, so t1about me->blog etc.

1. Is the above structure U1->T1->P1->T2->P2 a good approach? (I have around 30 million entries)
2. I need to modify the groovy script so that it can automatically add relationships and nodes in the same sequence. I was thinking to keep the previous user id in memory and if new user id=old id, then I will add only relationship and place. Otherwise, I will create a new user and build new path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your nodes are labeled `U` for users, `T` for timestamps, and `P` for pages.

1. You do not need timestamp nodes. You can, instead, put the timestamp value in the relationship between a `U` and a `P`. This will greatly reduce the number of nodes and relationships.

   For example, instead of this (I am making up the relationship
   types):

   ```
   (:U)-[:VISITED_AT]->(:T {timestamp: 123})-[:PAGE]->(:P)
   ```

   you can use this, which saves you 1 node and 1 relationship per visit:

   ```
   (:U)-[:VISITED {timestamp: 123}]->(:P)
   ```
2. What you describe seems reasonable, BUT you could create multiple nodes for the same page (e.g., `P1` in your example file, since it appears twice), whereas you really want to have one node per page. Also, if the file were to contain another `U1` row after the `U2` rows, you'd create a second `U1` node. To prevent such duplication, you should use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` for your `U` and `P` nodes. `MERGE` will create a node only if it does not already exist, else it just returns the existing node. Once you have the nodes, you can go ahead and `CREATE` the relationship (with the timestamp as a property) linking them together.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already have uniqueness constraint on users and pages.